# I need something to reconnect the server I was in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have to keep my PC on all night but sometimes I get disconnected from a Minecraft server. So, I need any software or .exe that press the "Back to server list" button and then reconnect the server I want to. Probably a macro would help because I have 5 minutes to reconnect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your best bet is to find an Auto Reconnect mod or use a client that has one. If you search on google "auto-reconnect Minecraft" some posts will come up about it. If you are getting disconnected for AFK, look into AFK machines if the server you are playing on allows then.